# Rename string value within an IF or IFELSE statement

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, data-manipulation

I need to replace a string value within my dataset, but the string I change it to depends on the value of another variable. I thought I was familiar with `if()` and `ifelse()` but this is my first time working with character vectors

`if()` won't work because there are multiple values in the vector that meet my criteria.

`ifelse()` isn't working because *I think* it's returning a completely new vector, so when I ask it to return a dataframe, it gets fussy.

This is the data I'm starting with:

| Filter_variable | String |
| --- | --- |
| A | No change needed |
| A | Starting Value |
| B | No change needed |
| B | Starting Value |

I've successfully changed my string variable with the following code:

```
dat$String[dat$String == "Starting Value"] = "End Value A"
```

But this changes every "Starting Value", regardless of what my filter value is doing

This is where I got stuck:

```
dat = dat %>%
  ifelse(dat$Filter_variable == "A", 
         dat$String[dat$String == "Starting Value" <- "End Value A", 
         dat$String[dat$String == "Starting Value"] <- "End Value B")
```

```
Error in ifelse(., dat$Filter_variable == "A", dat$String[dat$String ==  : 
  unused argument (dat$String[dat$String == "A"] <- "End Value A")
```

Comment: Only the first argument to ifelse is a conditional.

Comment: I'm hoping someone can share a good way to do this in base R, but I find `dplyr` simpler to work with where you want to do something to each "group" of data.

Comment: `library(dplyr); dat %>% mutate(String = if_else(row_number() == n(), paste("End value", Filter_variable), String), .by = Filter_variable)`? This should make a string like "End Value A" at the last appearance of each Filter_variable.

Comment: Is the output just a two-way decision - if Filter_variable is 'A' then 'End A', else everything goes to 'End B', or is it dependent on the Filter_variable values each time?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have misunderstood you here since you have not shared the expected output. However, based on my understanding you want to change the `"Starting Value"` values to `"End Value"` of corresponding `Filter_variable`.

You may use `ifelse` in the following way :

```
df <- transform(df, String = ifelse(String == "Starting Value", 
                       paste("End Value", Filter_variable), String))
df

#  Filter_variable           String
#1               A No change needed
#2               A      End Value A
#3               B No change needed
#4               B      End Value B
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you share data in a [reproducible format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

```
df <- structure(list(Filter_variable = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
String = c("No change needed", "Starting Value", "No change needed",
"Starting Value")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

[(Using `df` from the other answer by @Ronak Shah)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77945960/3560695)

### `ifelse`

From the help page of [`?ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse),

> `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test` which is filled with elements selected from either `yes` or `no` depending on whether the element of `test` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

In your case you want the lengths of `yes` and `no` to be the same. But you are calling `<-` for both `yes` and `no`. When using `ifelse`, what you want to do is call `<-` on the **result**.

But to encompass essentially two different conditions and an "otherwise", you would have to nest two `ifelse` with that approach:

```
df$String <-
    ifelse(
        df$Filter_variable == "A" & df$String == "Starting Value",
        "End Value A",
        ifelse(
            df$Filter_variable == "B" & df$String == "Starting Value",
            "End Value B",
            df$String
        )
    )
```

And for every level of `Filter_variable` you would have to add an additional nest. Not really a pretty solution!

### `data.frame` solution

A simple base R solution (`data.frame` solution) without `ifelse` could be like the following:

```
df$String[df$String == "Starting Value"] <- 
    paste("End Value", 
          df$Filter_variable[df$String == "Starting Value"])
```

*"For the subvector `df$String[df$String == "Starting Value"]`, redefine their values with `End value` concatenated with `df$Filter_variable[df$String == "Starting Value"]`"*

Generally I do not like this way of filtering `data.frame`s - here we use a filter twice and if we mistakenly change one without the other, it will do erroneous or unexpected behavior. And essentially we are not filtering on the rows, it's just a "coincidence" that the boolean vector from evaluating `df$String == "Starting Value"` has the appropriate length.

Result

```
  Filter_variable           String
1               A No change needed
2               A      End Value A
3               B No change needed
4               B      End Value B
```

### `data.table` solution

Instead, one could do a `data.table` approach to avoid this self referencing.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[String == "Starting Value", 
   String := paste("End Value", Filter_variable)]
```

Result:

```
   Filter_variable           String
            <char>           <char>
1:               A No change needed
2:               A      End Value A
3:               B No change needed
4:               B      End Value B
```